# Why week datepart for 30 Dec 2014 gives 1 instead of 53

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to get weekno. from a date in the following way:

```
DatePart("WW", "30/12/2014", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
```

However, its giving the result as 1, should it not give the result as 53? What is the role of vbMonday and vbFirstFourDays in this?

Comment: Well, as to the last comments from me and André, this result is correct. The buggy part of DatePart is seen the other way round - to return some weeks as 53 and not 1 as it would be should it follow the ISO 8601 Standard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DatePart("ww", <Date>, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)`

does calculate the ISO 8601 week number correctly **in most cases**.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date#First_week :

> The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the Gregorian year's **first Thursday** in it.
>   The following definitions based on properties of this week are mutually equivalent, since the ISO week starts with Monday:
>   * It is the first week with a majority (4 or more) of its days in January.
>   * etc.

2015-01-01 was a Thursday, so it is week 1 of 2015.

And so 2014-12-29 to 2014-12-31 are in week 1 of 2015 as well.

Comment: True, week 1 is correct for this date, but DatePart fails for many years.

Comment: Sorry, it's the other way round ... DatePart reports falsely some weeks for 53 while they are week 1. A reported week 1 will always be correct.

Answer (score 1):

That's because the *DatePart* function doesn't calculate according to the *ISO-8601 Standard*.

You will need a custom function like this to retrieve both the correct weeknumber and the corresponding year:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekYearNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date, _
  Optional ByRef intYear As Integer, _
  Optional ByRef bytWeek As Byte) _
  As String

' Calculates and returns year and week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' Optionally returns numeric year and week.
' 1998-2007, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53
  Const cbytMonthJanuary        As Byte = 1
  Const cbytMonthDecember       As Byte = 12
  Const cstrSeparatorYearWeek   As String = "W"

  Dim bytMonth                  As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  intYear = Year(datDate)
  bytMonth = Month(datDate)
  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(intYear, cbytMonthDecember, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000+ bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ' Adjust year where week number belongs to next or previous year.
  If bytMonth = cbytMonthJanuary Then
    If bytWeek >= cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear - 1 Then
      ' This is an early date of January belonging to the last week of the previous year.
      intYear = intYear - 1
    End If
  ElseIf bytMonth = cbytMonthDecember Then
    If bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear Then
      ' This is a late date of December belonging to the first week of the next year.
      intYear = intYear + 1
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekYearNumber = CStr(intYear) & cstrSeparatorYearWeek & Format(bytWeek, "00")

End Function
```

To check weeknumber:

```
Public Function ISO_WeekNumber( _
  ByVal datDate As Date) _
  As Byte

' Calculates and returns week number for date datDate according to the ISO 8601:1988 standard.
' 1998-2000, Gustav Brock, Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
' May be freely used and distributed.

  Const cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear  As Byte = 1
  Const cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear  As Byte = 53

  Dim bytWeek                   As Byte
  Dim bytISOThursday            As Byte
  Dim datLastDayOfYear          As Date

  bytWeek = DatePart("ww", datDate, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)

  If bytWeek = cbytLastWeekOfLeapYear Then
    bytISOThursday = Weekday(vbThursday, vbMonday)
    datLastDayOfYear = DateSerial(Year(datDate), 12, 31)
    If Weekday(datLastDayOfYear, vbMonday) >= bytISOThursday Then
      ' OK, week count of 53 is caused by leap year.
    Else
      ' Correct for Access97/2000 bug.
      bytWeek = cbytFirstWeekOfAnyYear
    End If
  End If

  ISO_WeekNumber = bytWeek

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate, but I cannot change the existing code of VBA as I am just migrating it to a newer technology. So, just wanted to know how it gives 1 instead of 53.

Comment: It just counts on as long as there are days left in the calendar year, ignoring if the days could belong to week 1 of the following ISO year.

Comment: For which dates is `DatePart("ww", <Date>, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)` wrong? `ISO_WeekYearNumber("2014-12-30")` returns `2015W01` as well.

Comment: You can run that expression and my function added to my answer in a loop covering a year range, and see which.

Comment: Not wanting to be a dick about it, but if you claim that `DatePart("ww"` calculates wrong, it is your job to provide an example.

Comment: Okay ... here's one: 2007-12-31.

Comment: :-o I stand corrected. `? ISO_WeekYearNumber("2007-12-31"), DatePart("ww", "2007-12-31", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)` -> `2008W01  53` --- While it doesn't answer the particular date of the question, this is very interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Andre: I've added a comment to the question to clarify and conclude.